# what do you have to review to get the 'do the swim' hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I'm fairly sure I've reviewed at least 5 new posts and/or late answers, but have yet to receive the *Do the swim* hat.

The description only says "review 5 items". What items am I supposed to review?

Comment: Give it time....

Comment: How long ago did you do the reviews? Some hats take longer to receive.

Comment: OK there we go, it has appeared. I guess I hadn't reviewed as much as I'd thought, up until now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have indeed [reviewed 5 items](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/47377/toryan?tab=activity&sort=reviews), but the 5th review was not until 5 minutes ago.

Give it a little time, it can take up to 15 minutes for hats to be awarded.